# Count external links from urls

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
public class Scanner {
    private HtmlProcessor hp;
    private String baseUrl;
    private int step = 0;

    public Scanner(String baseUrl) {
        this.hp = new HtmlProcessor();
        this.baseUrl = LinkParser.parseLink(baseUrl);
    }

    public void info(String url) throws IOException {


        String[] links =  hp.getLinksAndHrefs(url);
        System.out.println("Link : " + url + "\n"
                          +"ExtLinksCount : " + externalLinksCount(links) + "\n"
                          +"Steps to main : " + step
                          );
        String strippedLink;

        for (String link : links) {

            strippedLink = LinkParser.parseLink(link);

            if ( strippedLink.contains(this.baseUrl) && !strippedLink.equals(this.baseUrl) ) {
                ++ step; 
                info(link);
            }

            step = 0;
        }

    }

    public int externalLinksCount(String[] links) {
        int counter = 0;        

        String parsedLink;

        for (String link : links) {
             parsedLink = link;

            if ( ! ( parsedLink.contains( this.baseUrl ) ) ) {
                ++counter;
            }
        }


        return counter;

    }
}
```

We have some link on input : "http://test.com" 
this link has links : "http://test.com", "http://test.com/some", "http://google.com"
and "http://test.com/some" has links : "http://facebook.com", "some.com"

Needed result is :
Steps to main : 0
Link : "http://test.com"
ExtLinksCount : 1

Steps to main : 1
Link : "http://test.com/some"
ExtLinksCount : 2

I need to count all external links on this page and if this page has internal links go to the internal link and count all external links on this page and steps to return to the base page and so on.
I know how to get links from pages, but i don't know how to solve this problem correctly.
In my variant i resolving this problem with recursion. But if site has same as base link, program crashed.

Comment: What did you mean with "program crashed"? Does your program throw an exception, and if so which will be thrown?

Comment: Well.. recursion is dangerous in certain cases. You might have to confine yourself to certain "depth" to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2):

Recursion seems the way to go. However in recursion you should always define you exit strategy , otherwise you would end up in infinte loop.

Checking only if the url is equal to baseurl is not enough. if two subpages link to each other will cause infinite loop.

So i would suggest to keep list of parsed links. At the first link of ur info(), check if the list contains the URL, if yes, ignore & continue, else add to the list & process..

Modified Code

```
public class Scanner {
    private HtmlProcessor hp;
    private String baseUrl;
    private int step = 0;
    private List parsedLinks;

    public Scanner(String baseUrl) {
        this.hp = new HtmlProcessor();
        this.baseUrl = LinkParser.parseLink(baseUrl);
        this.parsedLinks = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void info(String url) throws IOException {
        if (!parsedLinks.contains(url)) {

            parsedLinks.add(url);

            String[] links = hp.getLinksAndHrefs(url);
            System.out.println("Link : " + url + "\n" + "ExtLinksCount : "
                    + externalLinksCount(links) + "\n" + "Steps to main : "
                    + step);
            String strippedLink;

            for (String link : links) {

                strippedLink = LinkParser.parseLink(link);

                if (strippedLink.contains(this.baseUrl)
                        && !strippedLink.equals(this.baseUrl)) {
                    ++step;
                    info(link);
                }

                step = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    public int externalLinksCount(String[] links) {
        int counter = 0;

        String parsedLink;

        for (String link : links) {
            parsedLink = link;

            if (!(parsedLink.contains(this.baseUrl))) {
                ++counter;
            }
        }

        return counter;

    }
}
```